4-5 games that crashes on launch on main windows 10 profile but they work on a newly created profiles. how can I fix the main profile?
The games are:
"dungeon siege 1 (on steam)", "nox (on gog)","void destroyer 2 (on steam)", "haydee (on steam)", "the escapists (on amazon games)", "Lichdom Battlemage(on steam)"
There are prolly many more that I haven't tried yet.
Every one of them works without doing anything on other profiles but crashes on launch on main profile.
Void destroyer 2: works on main profile when I disable every sound device on system. stops working even if one of them is enabled. Tried reinstalling openal dependency didn't work.
Haydee: tried reinstalling visual studio dependencies didn't work.
It could be linked to Realtek audio driver and sonic studio audio enchantment stuff but uninstalling all of them only makes the void destroyer work. (tried downgrading drivers or upgrading didn't work)
It could be language stuff because it is turkish locale device sometimes games don't like that but usually changing region settings to US fixed them for unity games but these one are not affected by that.
It could be an always on anti-cheat engine that I couldn't pinpoint I guess.
Tried disabling windows defender that didn't work.
Tried reinstalling physx driver didn't work.
It could be a group policy stuff that I messed with long time ago but don't know which one.
There is a reset profile guide on internet without appdata folder but I don't want to lose all my settings for my programs.
Well because they are working on other profies it is not a bad problem just wondering if any miracle person can come up with an answer to fix the main profile.

Okay fixed it. Every one of them working now. Culprit was a disabled service. (reset pc after enabling it) 
I disabled it couple of weeks ago because it was using gpu and I wasn't using any touchscreen or handwriting stuff. I guess it is connected to something deeper. I guess this was a very specific mess up but maybe helps someone else.

Backup and delete any saved games and settings folders in the user profile. Check e.g. PCGamingWiki.com for locations based on storefront. These files will not generally be removed by an uninstall.
Note that some of those games are extremely old and may be having their settings redirected since their assumptions on where to store things have changed by the OS over the years. It was common back then to need to blow away graphic settings when an update came out or a driver was updated because of capabilities changes and poor fallback in drivers and software.
